# Why std::unordered_map::rehash() is allowed to invalidate iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, unordered-map, invalidation

Visual Studio (2015) implementation does not invalidate any iterators (`rehash()` reorders internal `std::list`, keeping all iterators valid).

Are there other implementations, which invalidate iterators (and achieve better performance, even with the same complexity)?

Invalidating iterators on `std::unordered_map::rehash()` sometimes can limit developers (e.g. I'm trying to implement LRU cache with `std::unordered_map` only: with node's value having iterators to the container). But does the possibility to invalidate iterators allow to implement `std::unordered_map::rehash()` better?

Comment: Almost any standard container classes invalidate iterators on mutating operations, `std::list` is the exception.

Comment: Note that rehashing only invalidates iterators, but not pointers or references to elements. Since rehashing changes the order of the internal linked list, this makes sense. How would you define an operation of iterating over elements if their order changes in the middle of this operation?

Comment: Is there any reason why your LRU needs to store iterators? Can you switch to pointers or references?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ this is not the answer - why std::unordered_map can't be exception too?

Comment: Because two iterators that may be next to each other in before the rehash might not be after the rehash.

Comment: @DanielLangr, in order to invalidate LRU, I need unordered_map::iterator to erase(). And also to save next LRU iterator...

Non-const iteration over std containers is often not simple. But I hope this wasn't the only reason for allowing invalidation.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, so what? Standard could "invalidate" only non-const iteration over unordered_map, not every rehash().

Comment: @DanielLangr, I can store a pointer to unordered_map::value_type - it is NOT invalidated. But I'll be required to perform an awkward find() to get an iterator to the same node (and even more awkward search if I want to use unordered_multimap for some reason)

Comment: @Ilyan I see your point now. I am afraid that implementing an LRU cache with `std::unordered_map` won't be efficient. I now checked multiple questions about this problem, but all the suggested solutions triggered lookup while evicting elements from cache. Which is likely what you want to avoid. What you would need is a pointer to the `unrodered_map` _node_, which would not be invalidated after rehashing. But this functionality is not provided.

Comment: BTW, can you avoid rehashing by reserving the number of buckets? Set to the required LRU cache size plus setting the maximum load factor?

Comment: @DanielLangr, yes, reserving will work, but my question is NOT about implementing LRU cache (it was just an example, and probably I will even rely on VS non-invalidating implementation). I'm just curious about the reason the standard insists rehash() to invalidate iterators. What exactly did they thought of when they decided to limit users? Why was it so important for assumed rehash() implementations?

Comment: @Ilyan I guess the reason is as I wrote already. Rehashing changes the order of elements. Again, how would you define iterative operation if you change order in the middle?

Comment: If Microsoft STL guarantees no invalidation of iterators after rehashing, I guess that's the implementation issue. Don't know the internal details, but note that usually, each solution has pros and cons, so the MS implementation can have some drawbacks due to this design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DanielLangr for the discussion above,

I think, this requirement comes with `std::unordered_map::[const_]iterator` definition as `LegacyForwardIterator` (and not `LegacyBidirectionalIterator`). And an implementation with better memory footprint using internal `std::forward_list` or similar (instead of VS' `std::list`) is impossible without invalidating iterators in `rehash()` (probably, except `end()`).

- This better memory footprint implementations may add some [simple] assembly instructions here and there (also may save some in other places), or may have larger `sizeof(std::unordered_map::[const_]iterator)`, but it is definitely the right thing to define `std::unordered_map` requirements as they are, and leave all those considerations to implementers.